# Accessing JSON Body with C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, marshalling

I need to access the body of a JSON Code with C#. Accessing the header works but it does not work with the body and I could not find anything in the web.
I have this JSON Code

```
    `{
        "Example": {
            "Header": [
                [
                    "Header1",
                    "Header2",
                    "Header3",
                    "Header4"
                ]
            ],
            "Body": [
                {
                    "Header1": "BlaBla",
                    "Header2": 0,
                    "Header3": 20,
                    "Header4": 32
                },
{
                    "Header1": "BlaBlaBla",
                    "Header2": 22,
                    "Header3": 35,
                    "Header4": 25
                },
    ......`
```

However I can acess the headers with following code:

```
JArray headers = locationsObject["Header"] as JArray; 
JArray header = headers.Last as JArray; //Last Header
```

If I do the same with the body it is null:

```
JArray bodys = locationsObject["Body"] as JArray; //all bodys -> it works here
JArray body = bodys.First as JArray; //First body -> this one is null!!!
```

I need the integers in the body. I am using Newtonsoft for that. Can someone help me please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first body is not a **JArray** that could be the source of the problem, it is rather a **JObject**, you can try the following code, it should work fine

```
var bodys = locationsObject["Body"] as JArray;
var body = bodys[0];
```

you can use also [linq-to-json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) for more fine-tuned operations.

Comment: That was what I searching for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look at serializing/deserializing json in c#.
[How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

If you do not have a class representation of the json [json to c#](https://json2csharp.com/)

Your main line of code will be something like this:

```
exObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExampleObject>(jsonString);
```

And it will be:
string header1 = exObj.Body.Header1;

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by using the 'dynamic' variable type of C# which was specifically designed for functional programming languages. It is not type safe and not strong typed but you can access all the values in the result.

I would however strongly recommend you create classes that mimic the json you are trying to deserialize for it will give you strong typing and intellisense.

Here's an example how you can use dynamic. You need to install the NewtonSoft.Json Nuget package for this to function correctly.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace JsonDeserialized
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{
        'Example':
            {   'Header':
                [
                    [
                        'Header1',
                        'Header2',
                        'Header3',
                        'Header4'
                    ]
                ],
                'Body':
                [
                    {
                        'Header1': 'BlaBla',
                        'Header2': 0,
                        'Header3': 20,
                        'Header4': 32
                    },
                    {
                        'Header1': 'BlaBlaBla',
                        'Header2': 22,
                        'Header3': 35,
                        'Header4': 25
                    }
                ]
            }
        }";

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(result.Example);

            foreach (var header in result.Example.Header[0])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(header);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result.Example.Header[0][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

This program will print the following result.

---

```
{
  "Header": [
    [
      "Header1",
      "Header2",
      "Header3",
      "Header4"
    ]
  ],
  "Body": [
    {
      "Header1": "BlaBla",
      "Header2": 0,
      "Header3": 20,
      "Header4": 32
    },
    {
      "Header1": "BlaBlaBla",
      "Header2": 22,
      "Header3": 35,
      "Header4": 25
    }
  ]
}
Header1
Header2
Header3
Header4
Header1
```

---